# JSON - login form

Tags: android, mysql, json

i've been doing a login form by JSON encode, my code is like this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v==login){
login();
}
}

public void login(){

           String url_select = "http://ipadress/select.php";

           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

           //parameter
           ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

           try {
              //add parameter
               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

             HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
             HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

             //read content
             InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
             BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

             String content = "";
             String line = "";

             while((line = read.readLine())!=null){
                content += line;
             }

             Log.d("ADBUG", "content: "+content);


             //json
             if(!content.equals("null")){

                try {
                   JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(content);
                   String uname="";
                   String passw="";
                   String idx="";
                   for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++){
                      JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                      String id = jObj.getString("_id");
                      String username = jObj.getString("username");
                      String password = jObj.getString("password");
                      idx += id+"\n";
                      uname += username+"\n";
                      passw += password+"\n";
                   }

                    if(user.getText().toString().equals(uname) && pass.getText().toString().equals(passw)){
                        Intent a;
                        a = new Intent(this, WelcomeMenu.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
```

select.php :

```
<?php
include_once("koneksi.php");
$number_id= $_REQUEST['number_id'];

if($nomor_id){
   $sqlString = "select * from login where _id=$number_id";
}else{
   $sqlString = "select * from login";
}

$rs = mysql_query($sqlString);

if($rs){
   while($objRs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
      $output[] = $objRs;
   }

   echo json_encode($output);
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

the problem is i can't login, i've been insert username and password on my sql already, buat i can't login, anyone can help me? thanks before

Comment: where you are doing login? server side or mobile? Is anything return from server for the successful login?

Comment: i want to login from mobile, the server just keep the username and password which will be used for login, do u know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you fill the parameters?

```
       ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

Comment: i've tried this code to show all username and password in the database (username.settext() and password.settext()), and it work, but i've no idea whether i can use this code to login or not. do u know how to do it?

Comment: You don't seem to be adding the proper parameters to the post request. It's hard to tell from your code but it looks like you'd at least need to add 'number_id' to param before executing the request.

Comment: can u show me what kind of code? i'm really don't understand about this problem, thanks before